# How to guarantee that deferred JS scripts have executed?

Tags: javascript, deferred-loading

On my website I use javascript modules, which according to MDN are [deferred by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts). I have some additional javascript which can only safely execute once these modules have loaded and executed. MDN indicates [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) that deferred script execution is guaranteed to have occurred by the time the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired. Further, it is suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event#checking_whether_loading_is_already_complete) that you can also account for the case where this event has already fired like so:

```
function doSomething() {
  console.info('DOM loaded');
}

if (document.readyState === 'loading') {  // Loading hasn't finished yet
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doSomething);
} else {  // `DOMContentLoaded` has already fired
  doSomething();
}
```

The block above seems to be what I'm looking for. But documentation elsewhere on MDN leaves me unsure as to whether this is really correct. For instance, why does the `readystate` check above look for `loading` rather than `loading` OR `interactive`? The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) on `readystate` says that `loading` is followed by `interactive`, and that in the `interactive` state " sub-resources such as **scripts**, images, stylesheets and frames are **still loading**."

So it seems to me that there is an inconsistency here. Either the suggested `readystate` check is not sufficient to guarantee that `DOMContentLoaded` has fired, or `DOMContentLoaded` is not sufficient to guarantee that deferred scripts have completed.

Comment: `document.readyState` is not `loading` after `DOMContentLoaded` has fired - therefore, if it is not `loading` when you run that code, you don't need to wait (in fact you can't) for `DOMContentLoaded` to fire

Comment: @Bravo You're right, there's some confusion in my original post. I should have asked: why is the conditional not `document.readyState === 'loading' || document.readyState === 'interactive'`. I've updated my posted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When `readyState` is at least `interactive`, that means that the document has been fully parsed, and that all the elements in the source HTML now exist in the DOM.

Usually, people implementing this solution are doing so because they're trying to attach listeners to elements, and need to wait for all elements to exist in the DOM - and so all they need to do is check `document.readyState === 'loading'`.

If you also want to wait for `<script type="module">` scripts to run, that's a different problem, with a different solution.

The best way by far would be to have a single entry point for your app's in a module, so that you don't have to worry about loading order at all - it'll just work.

If you really have to determine when all module scripts have run from a non-module script (which I wouldn't recommend), you'd have to iterate over them and listen to their `load` events.

```
// run this at the end of the body -
// once all script tags exist, but before they've run
Promise.all(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('script[type="module"]')]
    .map(script => new Promise(
      resolve => script.addEventListener('load', resolve)
    ))
)
  .then(() => {
    // all module scripts are loaded
   })
```

But that's quite convoluted and probably isn't a good approach.

If you listen to the `load` event for the window instead, you'll also be waiting for all other resources to load as well (images and stylesheets and such) which isn't desirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import "other-module";
 // module is guaranteed to be loaded here
```

By importing the module one can guarantee that it is loaded before the module the import is in runs.